# live-reload not working in ionic 2, Anything need to change in configuration?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

when I am developing in ionic 2, whenever I make a coding/html change and save, the live-reload not working. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is an issue with the way ionic 2 RC.x versions which builds up - by default to a production build. Its a bug in the build scripts, i suppose.

So what you need to do is open up 2 terminals

run the

```
ionic run android  --livereload
```

and on the other terminal, type the following

```
npm run watch
```

That will solve the issue temporarily till the ionic team comes out with the fix.

Comment: Well, i'm on RC5 and with the **correct** script you **don't** need to do this anymore, but simply use **ionic run android -l**.
I can add a replay if you need more infos. Cheers

Comment: Also when I attempted to run the ionic 'run' command I got a message saying that the 'run' command was renamed - but what was it renamed to?